# Pivot table Macro not working (Error 1004 : Application defined or Object defined error)

Tags: excel, vba, macros

I'm creating a pivot table on the macro recorder and for some reason my macro is giving me this error. I've tread reading other SO problems on this similar error, however none of the solutions seem to be working. Here is the code

```
Sub macro5()
'
' macro5 Macro
'

'
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache. _
        CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Sheet5!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable3" _
        , DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion12
    Sheets("Sheet5").Select
    Cells(3, 1).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Employee/app.name")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable3").PivotFields("     Hours"), "Sum of      Hours", xlSum
End Sub
```

ERROR HERE

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache. _ CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Sheet5!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable3" _ , DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion12
```

Comment: Which line of code gives the error, and what is the error description? Is it "Unable to get the PivotTables property of the Worksheet class"?

Comment: The error is simply "application defined or object defined error" the same as the title. I also get an error on the first block of code, namely  ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache. _
        CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Sheet5!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable3" _
        , DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion12

Comment: What does the debugger tell you when you step through the code? Which **specific line** is causing the error?

Comment: It highlights the code that I wrote above your comment, in yellow.

Comment: Don't write it in the comments. Instead, [edit] your question where it can be seen and properly formatted.

Comment: Yup I did, You can see it above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating the pivot cache first and then the pivot table. Sample code snippet below. Also remember that destination sheets needs to be unique name each time you run this.

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "Pivot!R2C2:R6C5", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable _
    TableDestination:="Sheet5!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTabletest", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion12
```

Comment: What is pivot cache? Could you also tab the code and format in the one I gave, so its easier for me to understand? I don't really know VBA.

Comment: Now it says invalid procedure call or argument

Comment: invalid procedure call probably because my example used xlPivotTableVersion14 (Excel 2010) instead of your xlPivotTableVersion12 (Excel 2007). I have no success running recorded macro for pivots.

Comment: It works now, just fine. Could you see my new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38757461/taking-data-from-pivot-table-and-inserting-under-specific-headers