# Taking Data from pivot table and inserting under specific headers

Tags: excel, vba, macros

I just recently created a macro to make my pivot table and its working pretty good.

Heres how the format of the pivot table  pretty much looks. This file is called `Sheet1`

```
Name  Hours
Bob    100
Jones   200
Jilly   300
etc     etc
```

Now I have another file which is Called `Company`, and it comes with many headers at the top, which is read from a corporate website. Unfortunately among the headers it is missing a name and hours column. Heres how it currently Looks

```
Employee No.    Company Code   Cost Centre   Level  Organization Code etc   etc
```

I want it to look like `Employee No. Name  Hours   Company Code ...`

And the `name` and `hours` should just be taken from the pivot table. Any thoughts on how I could make a script to do this? Thanks.

**MORE INFO**

Originally there is a file named **Cado**

**Cado** has many headers i.e

```
Pers.No   Employee    Date   Hours   Time  ...       ...  
12345      Bob         June   6
123324     joe         June    5
12345      Bob         June   5
243123     Smith        June  5.5
```

I succesfully made a macro for this which creates a pivot table named **Sheet1**

The pivot table looks like this

```
Pers.No  Sum of Hours
12345         11
123324         5
 etc           etc
```

Notice how this takes the total sum, even though there are duplicates with the same name and Id in the original sheet.

Now there is one more file called **Company** It currenly has

```
 Employee no. Level Organization code   Manager organization code etc
```

I automatically get this excel file.

What I want to do is take the PIVOT TABLE `Sheet One`, and make two more columns in middle or at the end of the new **Company File** it doesent matter say

```
Employee no. Level  Organization code Pers.No  Hours    etc   etc
```

These two added headers should simply take all the data from the pivot table ( as it is already sorted and in order, so this would be easier than reading from the original file called **Cado**)

Comment: There isn't enough information to answer your question. For example, how would you know which Name corresponds to which Employee No. ?

Comment: You need to find a commonality between the two tables.  If you provide more details it will be easier to help out.  In your `company` file, do you have any column that may help identify the employee name?  You mention etc, etc, so maybe there is.

Comment: The pivot table already orders employee I'd with hours

Comment: And yes nickstoy there is an employee Id which in the original data matches with the employee name. But the pivot table I have now just matches someone's name with their own hours. I just need to almost copy and paste it if you will into this company file sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if file 'Company' is a pivot or not. But, if not, then if both files contain the Employee No. you could simply use a vlookup to pull in the name and hours off of the pivot.

Comment: Sheet1 is a pivot. I would like to make a macro, so someone else who doesent know much about excel can just do this on click.

Comment: There is no way to merge columns from 2 pivots. You can use code to combine the datasets prior to creating one all-inclusive pivot. Other option is to run a for...next loop on each employee no. in company pivot and bring name and hours values from pivot sheet1 into the row on company pivot, but it won't be contained within the pivot and won't refresh with any pivot changes. If that is your thought let me know and I can post sample code.

Comment: The file Company is not a pivot it is a sheet with many columns like I showed above In the second "picture", sheet1 is a pivot. I want to insert two columns into the Company file which is just a sheet with information on it. The information I want to insert is just the pivot table info itself. I can add some pictures if this is still unclear in my question

Comment: Added lots of detail in the description of the question, please check it out